# Why does Underscore's clone function use array slice?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, clone, slice

There are lines in Underscore

```
  _.clone = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    return _.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : _.extend({}, obj);
  };
```

And I have no idea why `obj.slice()` was used here to return a obj(array).

If `_.isArray(obj)` is true, the return becomes `obj.slice().`

#### Question

As far as I know, `array.slice` without parameters does nothing. I think it should be just `obj` rather than `obj.slice()`.

Is there any reason `obj.slice()` was used in this line?

Answer (score 4):

This function should **clone** something, thus create a **new array**. If you return `obj`, there is no cloning at all. From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), `array.slice()`:

> returns a new array containing the extracted elements.

Calling `slice()` is a simple way to make a copy of the array. But note that this method only performs a **shallow copy** (vs a *deep copy*): with nested arrays (or arrays of objects), the items will keep the same address. Here is a simple example:

```
var o1 = {"name": "henry"};
var o2 = {"name": "jean"};

var a1 = [o1, o2];
var a2 = a1.slice();

a2[0].name = "modified";

console.log(a1[0].name); // --> "modified"
console.log(a1[0] === a2[0], a1[0] === o1); // --> true
```

Comment: You are right. I added this detail in my answer, which might be useful.

Comment: I think there's no use of shallow copy. I think the result is almost same with using obj rather than obj.slice(). Is there any possible reason to copy obj shallow?